# Optimal angle to jump off a swing to maximise air time

Tags: optimization, dynamical-systems, physics

When on a swing of length $l$ and height $h$ above the ground at rest, swinging to a max angle $\theta_{max}$ from the vertical, at what angle $\theta$ from the vertical should you let go of the swing to maximise the length of time you spend in the air?

Related: [Ideal angle to launch from a swing to maximize distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355337/ideal-angle-to-launch-from-a-swing-to-maximize-distance)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start by writing the velocity at the point of release (from conservation of energy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I derived the travel time in the question you linked:

\begin{align*}
t&=\frac{v_y}{g}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2g(y+h)}{v_y^2}}\right) \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2\ell}{g}}\left(\xi+\sqrt{\xi^2+1+h/\ell-\cos\theta}\right)
\end{align*}

where $\xi=\sin\theta\sqrt{\cos\theta-\cos\theta_m}$

and like before you now take $\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=0$ and solve for $\theta$